# FIDO Authentication using windows hello and webauth

Tags: fido

Would like to implement FIDO authentication for our web application using 'windows hello' as authenticator & 'WebAuthn' protocol.
Please let me know the steps involved.

- Which windows OS version & its build version supports windows hello ?
- How to set up FIDO server?
- How to integrate our web application with FIDO server?
- Is FIDO can be used to authenticate back end web api end point access?

Answer (score 0):

1. FIDO2 functionality was initially released in [Windows 10 version 1803](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/)
2. Set up a FIDO Server - You'll need to make a couple design decisions first.

   2.1. Pay an IAM solution provider that already offers WebAuthn / FIDO2.

   2.2. Build WebAuthn / FIDO2 functionality into your existing authentication system.

   2.2.1 Integrate with an authentication service. The authentication service hosts the infrastructure, your app just calls their API.

   2.2.2 Spin up standalone WebAuthn / FIDO2 servers on your own infrastructure and integrate it with your existing authentication system.

   2.2.3 Integrate WebAuthn / FIDO2 libraries into your existing authentication system (uses existing infrastructure).
3. How you integrate depends on your design decisions outlined above. If you want to learn about integrating a library into your existing authentication system then I would recommend [Yubico's Passwordless Workshop](https://github.com/YubicoLabs/java-webauthn-passwordless-workshop).
4. WebAuthn / FIDO2 supports various uses cases. [Learn more at the FIDO Alliance](https://fidoalliance.org/fido2/).

Comment: Above mentioned steps seems to be complex & involved some licenses procurement so before making changes to actual application, to understand low level complexities involved in incorporating FIDO by doing  POC means from where to start? Please guide/suggest open source server to do FIDO authentication, open source for 'Authenticator' & how to integrate between FIDO server & POC appilcation for authentication?

Comment: Please reply for above questions.

Comment: There are a couple catalogs where you can find products and services that support FIDO authentication:
* [FIDO Alliance Certified Showcase](https://fidoalliance.org/fido-certified-showcase/)
* [Works With YubiKey Catalog](https://www.yubico.com/works-with-yubikey/catalog/)

Comment: Since you mention Windows Hello, I would suggest you look at Azure Active Directory. [AAD Works With YubiKey Resources](https://www.yubico.com/works-with-yubikey/catalog/azure-active-directory/) [AAD Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-authentication-passwordless#fido2-security-keys)

Comment: herrjemand maintains a [list of open source WebAuthn resources](https://github.com/herrjemand/awesome-webauthn) as well.